# NestJs async httpService call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

How can I use Async/Await on `HttpService` using NestJs?
The below code doesn`t works:

```
async create(data) {
    return await this.httpService.post(url, data);
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `HttpModule` uses `Observable` not `Promise` which doesn't work with async/await. All `HttpService` methods return `Observable<AxiosResponse<T>>`.

So you can either transform it to a `Promise` and then use await when calling it or just return the `Observable` and let the caller handle it.

```
create(data): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return this.httpService.post(url, data).toPromise();
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Note that `return await` is almost (with the exception of try catch) always redundant.

### Update 2022

`toPromise` is deprecated. Instead, you can use `firstValueFrom`:

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

// ...

return firstValueFrom(this.httpService.post(url, data))
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, toPromise is deprecated

Answer (score 28):

As `toPromise()` is being deprecated, you can replace it with `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom`

For example:

```js
const resp = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/myApi`)
```

https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Comment: save my life.. thank you

Answer (score 8):

rxjs library is most powerful concurrency package that chosen form handling system event like click, external request like get data or delete record and ....

The main concept behind this library is:

> ***handle data that receive in future***

therefor you most use 3 argument in observable object like

```
observablSource.subscribe(
   data => { ... },
   failure => { ... },
   compelete => { ... }
)
```

but for most *backend developer* use ***Promises*** that comes from [ECMAScript 6 feature](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage) and is native part of JavaScript.

By default in [Angular 4+](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and [Nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers) use ***rxjs*** that support **Observable**. In technical details you can find a solution for change automatic observable to promise.

```
const data: Observable<any>;
data.from([
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'mahdi'
   }, 
   {
      id: 2,
      name: 'reza'
   },
 ])
```

now you have simulate a request with observable type from server. if you want to convert it to ***Pormise*** use chained method like example:

```
   data.toPromise();
```

from this step you have promised object and form using it better to attach ***async/await***

```
 async userList( URL: string | URLPattern ) {
    const userList = await this.http.get<any>( URL ).toPromise();
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mahdi! That was what I did!

Answer (score 2):

try these below one instead of only async-await.

There are some basic reasons behind the deprecation of toPromise.

We know that Promise and Observables that both collections may produce values over time.
where  Observables return none or more and Promise return only one value when resolve successfully.

there is a main reason behind the seen

- Official: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise
- Stack:[Rxjs toPromise() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044273/rxjs-topromise-deprecated)

Now we have 2 new functions.

- lastValueFrom : last value that has arrived when the Observable completes for more https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom
- firstValueFrom:  you might want to take the first value as it arrives without waiting an Observable to complete for more https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom

Answer (score 1):

Following is complete example for working code:

.toPromise() is actually missing

```
async getAuthToken() {
    const payload = {
      "SCOPE": this.configService.get<string>('SCOPE'),
      "EMAIL_ID": this.configService.get<string>('EMAIL_ID'),
      "PASSWORD": this.configService.get<string>('PASSWORD'),
    };
    const url = this.configService.get<string>('AUTHTOKEN_URL')
    const response = await this.httpService.post(
      url,
      payload
    ).toPromise();
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the .toPromise() at the end of each method call but then you lose the power of observables, like it’s ability to add retry to failed http call by just adding the retry operator.

You can implement this abilities by yourself and create your own module or just use package that already implemented it like this :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-http-promise

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29789100)

Comment: Changed the answer to include the main parts here :)