# Rxjs toPromise() deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have read that `toPromise()` is being deprecated in RxJS 7 and will be removed in RxJS 8.
I have often used it with async await syntax in angular to handle http calls. Is it considered an anti pattern?
I understand the concept of streams but an http call only emit a single value. I don't get the point of observable for a simple http call. What should I use next? should I fully embrace reactive programming?

Comment: As is conventional, the alternatives are provided in the deprecation: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/aa9ab6b555203529a699b3a79531a57b7d78fefa

Answer (score 135, accepted):

***Why is this happening?***

As mentioned [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated#why-is-this-happening-to-me), these are the main reasons why `toPromise` is being deprecated:

> 1. One goal was to remove it from the `Observable` prototype and turn it into a standalone util function.
> 2. The naming of `toPromise` is not the best. Especially when used in combination with `await` it does not read very well: `await categories$.toPromise()` vs `await lastValueFrom(categories$)`
> 3. The type information of `toPromise` is wrong. When the source `Observable` completed without ever emitting a single value - it
>    resolved with `undefined`. It should reject in that case. A `Promise` is a
>    "promise" that when it resolves a value will be there - and be it
>    `undefined`. But when the stream completes without ever emitting a value
>    you can't differentiate between a stream that a emitted `undefined` on
>    purpose and a stream that completed without ever emitting anymore

***What should you use next?***

If you really insist doing it the promise way, `lastValueFrom`/`firstValueFrom`. Otherwise switching to reactive programming would be the way to go.

Using `toPromise` ( deprecated ) -

```
public async loadCategories() {
    this.categories = await this.inventoryService
      .getCategories()
      .toPromise()
}
```

Using `lastValueFrom` ( new ) -

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

public async loadCategories() {
    const categories$ = this.inventoryService.getCategories();
    this.categories = await lastValueFrom(categories$);
}
```

This link should help -

https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Comment: thanks for the reply and for the link, it was what I was looking for

Answer (score 32):

`firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` is definitly a better alternative for many reasons:

1. The naming is more readable and self explanatory.
2. The additional ability to select either first or last value.
3. The additional ability to declare a default value in case the observable didn't emit any value at all like so `await lastValueFrom(data$, {defaultValue: 'Some default value'})`

For more about this checkout the video below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aeK5SfWBSU

Answer (score 28):

**Code example:**

Deprecated use:

```
await this.http.post<boolean>(`/someApi`).toPromise()
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(`Result: ` + value);
  })
```

New code:

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

await firstValueFrom(this.http.post<boolean>(`/someApi`))
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(`Result: ` + value);
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

For the most stubborn, I've found this workaround to keep toPromise() forever. Put this in your main.ts or similar (the file that gets to boostrap the entire application):

```
declare module "rxjs" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        /**
         * Extension method. Applies 'lastValueFrom' to Observable<T>.
         */
        toPromise(): Promise<T | undefined>;
    }
}

Observable.prototype.toPromise = function <T>(this: Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
    return lastValueFrom(this);
};
```

The first part declares the new typing for toPromise, and the second bit actually implements it. This works already while toPromise hasn't been yet removed, and will continue working going forward.

Comment: This is DANGEROUS. It changes semantics - `toPromise` resolves the promise successfully with undefined value if the observable ends without emitting any value. `lastValueFrom` will reject the promise. I personally wouldn't use it as global polyfill without reviewing all usages. See https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#use-default-value for proper replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I personally used:

```
// From my Component
const apiResponse = await lastValueFrom(this.postSomethingAPI(somethingId, somethingElseId));

// From my Service
postSomethingAPI = (somethingId: string, somethingElseId: string) => {
   const queryParams = `someParameter`;
   const packagedData = {
      somethingId: somethingId,
      somethingElseId: somethingElseId,
   };
   return this.http.post<any>(BACKEND_URL + queryParams, packagedData);
};
```