# Angular 13 - How to resolve '(): Promise<Object | undefined>' is deprecated.ts(6385)

Tags: angular

In my Angular-13 project, I am trying to get the data from API endpoint for chartjs. I have this in the service:

```
  getCurrentEmployeeChart() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'current-employee')
        .toPromise()
        .then((data) => {
          return data;
        });
  }
```

I got this error:

> '(): Promise<Object | undefined>' is deprecated.ts(6385)
> Observable.d.ts(125, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Then:

> toPromise()

is crossed.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044273/rxjs-topromise-deprecated

Comment: Why you want promise , observable can do the same job for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Most likely you want to use `lastValueFrom`

```
import { interval, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

async function execute() {
  const source$ = interval(2000).pipe(take(10));
  const finalNumber = await lastValueFrom(source$);
  console.log(`The final number is ${finalNumber}`);
}
```