# Angular : read config file at runtime without using Promise

Tags: angular

I'm trying to read a config file at *runtime* using Angular 12. In all the example I saw, a ConfigService class is used in conjuction with the APP_INITIALIZER to read the file using http.get when the app is initialized. All of them are using toPromise() (to wait until the file has been successfully read). However, toPromise will be deprecated in the next rxjs version.

So, how can we read a config file, at runtime, and make sure that the file has been read *before* the application can be used without using promises?

Comment: use lastValueFrom operator as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044273/rxjs-topromise-deprecated

Comment: I think an APP_INITIALIZER also supports a plain observable now. Just make sure it completes.