# Alternative to toPromise with downgradeInjectable

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-promise, ng-upgrade

A service I've written in Angular is being consumed in a third party angularJS application. My pattern has been: create a service method which returns `Observable<someType>` and then create a wrapper for that method returning a `Promise<someType>`.
e.g.

```
getDetails(a: string, b: number) : Observable<IMyType> { ... }
getDetailsPromise(a: string, b: number) : Promise<IMyType> { 
  return this.getDetails(a, b).toPromise(); 
}
```

The service is then used in the 3rd party AngularJS application using `downgradeInjectable` and the angularJS code uses the "Promise" version of the service functions.

As `toPromise` is being deprecated in RxJS 8, what is the alternative to continue allowing the angularJS application to access async Service functions from the Angular Library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rxjs toPromise() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044273/rxjs-topromise-deprecated)